# How to make recyclerView_items unclickable, while one of them is clicked and working?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, clickable

## Premise

Each of my RecyclerView_items displays an image, and changes its image_resource when tapped.
One of them is the right answer which has additional function: navigation to another fragment 5-second after changing its image.

Basically, the function of clickListener of RecyclerView_items is

- *wrong item*
  click -> change image_resource
- *right item*
  click -> change image_resource -> `delay(5000)` -> navigate to another fragment

## Problem

Then, my problem is that after the right_item is tapped, other items are clickable during `delay(5000)`.
I don't want them to change their images during `delay(5000)`.

How to do it?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may take a boolean and make it true when right image is clicked and check it onclick on other image if it is false, then only change image else navigate to another fragmnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a flag at time when user click right image then make that variable false. As such after the delay before moving to the next fragment make it true again.

```
boolean flag = true;
```

then in your item click method

```
view.setOnClickListner {
 if (flag) {
   if (rightimageclicked) {
       flag = false;
       delay { 
        flag = true;
        // Move to other fragment  
       }
   } else {
       // change the image for wrong click
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple trick you can use is make a `FrameLayout` or `View` that overlaps on the `RecyclerView`. Set ists `visibility` to `GONE`. Then inside activity or fragment where you can access this `FrameLayout` or View which is overlapping, add an empty `OnClickListener` on this view.

```
*viewId*.setOnClickListener { }
```

Now set its `visibility` to `VISIBLE` when you call delay. When delay finished again set its `visibility` to `GONE`

Comment: Your answer made it! Thanks, sir!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood, you want to lock the entire screen (make all items or buttons unclickable) when you are in `delay(5000)`. 
This is what I would do, give a **CLICKABLE overlay view on top of recycler view** and toggle its visibility.
 I used the same for locking the entire screen while making an API call.
***view_overlay.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously you can replace **ProgressBar** with just **View** to get a transaprent view.

 
 To include it in your main view, give this at the bottom of your parent layout or below recycler view. Whichever you choose make sure you have the overlay view on top of recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...
    ...
    ...

    <include layout="@layout/view_overlay" />
</RelativeLayout>
```